# Visual Studio IDE - how to insert snippet on one tab click?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I use Visual Studio IDE for C#. By default, you need to click "Tab" button twice to insert a snippet. Is it possible to insert snippet with only one "Tab"? please suggest me settings or extension.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question.
No, it is not possible to do that.

But there is a "trick" to make it feel like a TAB.

You hold TAB a little bit longer (but is no longer effetiv as pressing TAB 2 times).